# 'Symbol's value as variable is void' in callback from url-retrieve

Tags: flycheck, lexical-scoping

When executing the following I get an error:

```
(defun caller (func)
  (url-retrieve "http://m0smith.freeshell.org/"
   (lambda (status) (funcall func))))


(caller (lambda() (message "called")))
```

Result:

```
error in process filter: Symbol's value as variable is void: func
```

What is the best way to solve this problem?  Basically I need to accept a callback from somewhere else, wrap it in another lambda and use that as the callback to url-retrieve.

If I change caller to

```
(defun caller (func)
  (url-retrieve "http://m0smith.freeshell.org/"
   `(lambda (status) (funcall ,func))))
```

it works.  However, I cannot do this as func is being passed by flycheck and the macro expansion breaks it.  To see the full context of what I am doing: https://gist.github.com/m0smith/b5961fda6afd71e82983

Comment: *What macro expansion?* Your last paragraph is unclear. Post here a full explanation of the problem. Using backquote with comma **is** the solution (one solution). Another could be to use `lexical-let` or setting variable `lexical-binding`. Please make clear what the problem is with the not-shown "macro".

Comment: I assumed the ` and , were macro expanded.  Whatever that form is called then.  I would like to work in EMACS 23.  Is there a lexical feature available?

Comment: If there is no use of `FUNC` beyond the `funcall` then logically you do **not** need lexical binding here. There is nothing wrong with using it, but you do not *need* it, unless some code actually needs to make use of the *variable* `FUNC`. If you do not need it (which is what it looks like, so far), then just replace its occurrence by its value, using backquote with comma.

Comment: Lexical binding is available in Emacs 23 (and prior), using `lexical-let`. The global variable `lexical-binding` is available in Emacs 24.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this locally by using cl.el's *lexical-let*:

```
(eval-when-compile '(require 'cl))

(defun my-test-caller (func)
  (lexical-let ((ext-func func))
    (url-retrieve "http://www.google.com"
                  (lambda (status) (funcall ext-func)))))

(my-test-caller #'(lambda() (message "called")))
```

To be explicit as the help says:

```
Like `let', but lexically scoped.
The main visible difference is that lambdas inside BODY will create
lexical closures as in Common Lisp.
```

Now you can get the same effect by enabling [lexical-binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html) which was added in Emacs 24.1. This is a buffer local variable that can be set and will enable lexical closures on **all code** in the buffer. So your buffer would look like this:

```
;; -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

(defun my-lexical-test-caller (func)
  (url-retrieve "http://www.google.com"
                (lambda (status) (funcall func))))

(my-lexical-test-caller
 #'(lambda()
     (message "called from lexical-binding def")))
```

Comment: Thanks.  However I get `my-test-caller: Symbol's function definition is void: lexical-let` in my emacs: GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)` of 2014-10-20 on KAEL

Comment: @MSmith - ahh add (require 'cl)

Comment: `lexical-let` is defined in `cl-macs.el`. So `(eval-when-compile '(require 'cl))`

Comment: You don't need to require `cl.el` at runtime, just for this. `lexical-let` is a macro, so it is enough to require it at compile time.

Comment: Please don't.  Use `lexical-binding`.  Flycheck doesn't support Emacs 23 anyway, so there's no point in trying to be compatible with it.

Answer (score 5):

Enable `lexical-binding` for your library, with `M-x add-file-local-variable-prop-line RET lexical-binding RET t`.

Please do not use `lexical-let` as suggested by the other answer.  Flycheck itself is not compatible with Emacs 23, so there is no point in trying to maintain Emacs 23 compatibility in your own code.

Comment: Thanks. That will help so I am not trying to get the older emacs working for no reason

Comment: What's wrong with using lexical-let for this?

Comment: @stsquad It's slower and more verbose.  With `lexical-binding` there is no need for an additional binding, because the argument itself is lexically scoped.  Moreover, `lexical-binding` creates true closures, whereas `lexical-let` uses uninterned symbols to emulate lexical binding.

Comment: @lunaryorn: isn't there a risk by enabling lexical-binding on a existing buffer of legacy code you may get unforeseen effects? Anyway I've expanded my answer to mention both solutions.

Comment: @stsquad Yes, there *could* be unforeseen effects in poorly written legacy code which relies on `let` binding undefined variables dynamically.  But again, Flycheck is for Emacs 24 anyway, so we are not talking about legacy code.