# What are the potential pitfalls of enabling lexical-binding for a buffer?

Tags: elisp, lexical-scoping

This was inspired by the discussion of *[lexical-binding](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Lexical-Binding.html)* vs *lexical-let* in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/4265/symbols-value-as-variable-is-void-in-callback-from-url-retrieve). As *lexical-binding* gives you the ability to have useful closures people may be used to in other languages like JavaScript why wouldn't you enabled it all the time?

Assuming backwards compatibility with older Emacsen is not a concern what pitfalls should you be looking for if enabling it in legacy code buffers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A major pitfall is that the binding semantics for **undefined** variables—i.e. variables not defined with `defvar` and friends—change with `lexical-binding`:  Without it, `let` binds everything dynamically, but with `lexical-binding` enabled undefined variables are bound **lexically**, and even elided completely if unused in the current lexical scope.

Old code sometimes relies on this.  To avoid hard dependencies for optional features, it'd bind dynamic variables **without** requiring the corresponding library or declaring the variable itself:

```
(let ((cook-eggs-enabled t))
  (cook-my-meal))
```

If the cooking feature is optional, we don't want to force unnecessary dependencies onto the user, so we don't use `(require 'cook)` and instead rely on autoloading of the `cook-my-meal` function.

It's obvious for the human reader that `cook-eggs-enabled` is not a local variable, but still refers to some global dynamic variable from the `cook` library here.  Without `lexical-binding` this code works as intended:  `cook-eggs-enabled` is bound dynamically, whether defined or not.

With `lexical-binding` however, it breaks:  `cook-eggs-enabled` is now bound **lexically** (and then optimized away, because it's not used), so the global dynamic variable `cook-eggs-enabled` is **not** ever touched at all and still  `nil` by the time `cook-my-meal` is called, so we surprisingly won't have any eggs in our meal.

Luckily, these issues are **very easy to spot**: The byte compiler naturally **warns** about an unused lexical binding here.

The fix is simple:  Either add a `(require 'cook)` (for features that aren't really optional anyway), or—to avoid hard dependencies—declare the variable as dynamic variable **in your own code**.  There is a special `defvar` form for this:

```
(defvar cook-eggs-enabled)
```

This defines `cook-eggs-enabled` as dynamic variable, but doesn't affect the docstring, the `load-history` (and thus `find-variable` and friends) or anything else, except the binding nature of the variable.

Comment: In the dynamic case, wouldn't that code snippet cause `cook-eggs-enabled` to be *unbound* when `let` finishes? I'm pretty sure I've run into a bug like this before. The defvar was happening inside the `let`, and the `let` later restored the variable to its initial (void) state.

Comment: @Malababa No, that is a different situation.  See the last paragraph of [Defining Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Defining-Variables.html) for the reason.